# Two logically identical C instructions give different results

Tags: c, operators, xor

EDIT: The answer is, bitwise operations on signed values does weird things!

During a debugging process, I noticed a weird discrepancy, and I have translated it into an easy to read example below.

It would seem to me that var1 and var2 should be identical: after carefully stepping through this on a debugger, it seems that var1 and var2 are identical for the first iteration, but diverge for the second. I discovered this bug while trying to convert the expression for "var2" into assembly, and noticed that my logical translation (which I've displayed with "var1") was giving different results. The calculation for "var1" is, to me, an identical unpicking of the complex expression for "var2" - where am I going wrong?

This was compiled with Visual Community 2019, x64, debug.

```c
// x is an unsigned char, equivalent to the length of the string
// taking the null terminator into account

unsigned char var1 = x;
unsigned char var2 = x;

for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    unsigned char temp1 = string[i];
    unsigned char temp2 = var1 ^ temp1;
    unsigned char temp3 = table[temp2];

    var1 ^= temp3;
    var2 ^= table[var2 ^ string[i]];
}
```

Comment: I imagine that `string` was declared as `unsigned char *string;` or `unsigned char string[x];`, right?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli it's a ```char* string``` actually

Comment: `var2^string[i]` ends up being > 255? Read about integral promotions

Comment: No - they're all bound correctly from 0-255, and diverge only in fact halfway through the XOR-ing

Comment: Somewhere between the steps of ```temp2``` and ```temp3``` the expression for var2 generates a different result

Comment: Make `string ` `unsigned char*`

Comment: Avoid doing bitwise operations with signed variables.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why? in terms of bitwise xor, signed/unsigned is immaterial - bits are bits, no? Where in the two logical statements is there a signed discrepancy? If it works, I'll thank you, but I'll still be confused!

Comment: *No - they're all bound correctly from 0-255, and diverge only in fact halfway through the XOR-ing* And only when the most significant bit of the `char` value is `1`, right?  As commented earlier, read about integral promotion.

Comment: I haven't checked that @AndrewHenle but it would seem everyone says its a signed issue - why? why does xor of some bits vary with the sign

Comment: The `^` performs integer promotion, and your `string[i]` will get sign-extended if happens to be negative. So this will go to the weeds: `table[var2 ^ string[i]]`

Comment: Turn on all your warnings.  A good compiler should warn about doing this.

Comment: There's not enough code here to fully reproduce the problem.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run and get the same result you do.

Comment: I implemented this in x64 assembly - how would my assembler have known about the signs?

Comment: There is no assembly in the question.

Comment: Well thank you all - changing it to an ```unsigned char*``` solved the problem! I would never have noticed that

Comment: The assembler knows only what you tell it. The *programmer* distinguishes between signed and unsigned by the choice of instructions.

Comment: @WeatherVane I actually prefer the results from the signed version - how would I go about a "signed" xor?

Comment: This is one of those questions that really shows the importance of understanding undefined behavior! :D

Comment: My response was to your comment: *"I implemented this in x64 assembly"* where there is no such thing as a signed `xor`. Any signedness come from the way you handle the operation's flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `table[var2 ^ string[i]];`, the `var2` has an `unsigned char` value of 0 to 255, and `string[i]` may have a signed `char` value of −128 to +127. (We assume eight-bit bytes and two’s complement, which are ubiquitous in modern systems.)

As is usual with most C operators, the *integer promotions* are applied to the operands, which, in this case, produces `int` operands. For the `unsigned char` values 0 to 255, this produces an `int` with bits set only in the low eight bits. For `char` values −128 to −1, this produces an `int` with bits set throughout the `int`, particularly in the high bits.

Then the result of the XOR operation is an `int` with high bits set, including the sign bit, so it has a negative value. Then `table` is indexed with a negative subscript, going outside the bounds of the array. And so the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

To remedy this, change the element type of `table` to `unsigned char` or convert `string[i]` to `unsigned char` before using it in bitwise operations.

Comment: I ripped the signed code from Wikipedia and it worked just fine; both on debug and on Release mode the full version is entirely defined and functional:
 ```unsigned char cHash = cLen;
for (int i = 0; i < cLen; ++i) cHash ^= cPerm256[cHash ^ csString[i]];``` works cleanly and produces a uniform hash. The unsigned version produces a terribly low quality hash, and I would like to implement the _signed_ version in an assembly file. How might I do this integer promotion thing myself?

Comment: Merely changing "csString" into ```unsigned char*``` breaks the quality of the hash, so in my assembly implementation it is necessary that I perform the integer promotion myself.

Comment: @IdioticShrike *I ripped the signed code from Wikipedia*  Well, you just learned about the quality of Wikipedia.  With a signed conversion, the `cPerm256` array needs to have 2 gig of elements in the positive direction and 2 gig of elements in the negative direction, assuming 32-bit `int` values.  If it doesn't, the code is ***BROKEN***.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The Wikipedia code worked flawlessly! Also I translated it from Python to C so the signed issue may well not be wikipedia's fault... But it works nicely - the "correct" unsigned version does not.

Comment: @IdioticShrike Then you should have used `unsigned char` [just like the Wikipedia example actually does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing#C,_64-bit).  So you didn't get the signed code off Wikipedia.